# How do we check which version of Sonar C# plugin support which version of C#.Net version?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Currently I'm using SonarQube 6.0 with C# plugin 5.xx. I would like to know which verion of SonarQube's C# plugin support C#.Net(3.5,4,4.5,5.0,6.0) language latest features.

Comment: C# (5.5.1+) and Framework(4.5.2+) support latest features of `SonarQube` (5.6+)

Comment: There aren't any or aren't a lot of rules that would be specific to language version. If you're using msbuil14 then you can use C# 6 features. If you're on msbuild12 then you can only use C# 5 ones. msbuild15 is not yet supported by the Scanner for MsBuild, so there's no C# 7 feature support yet.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any or aren't a lot of rules that would be specific to the language version. If you're using msbuild14 then you can use C# 6 features. If you're on msbuild12 then you can only use C# 5 ones. msbuild15 is not yet supported by the Scanner for MsBuild, so there's no C# 7 feature support yet.